# How to add "star" symbol next to the number of the equation?

Tags: equations

How to add a "star" symbol next to the number of the equation such as

y=x+z                 ....       (8*)

Thanks

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436)  Do you also want to reference this equation later on? Will there also be an equation with the number 8 (without the asterisk)?

Comment: Do you also have an equation 8 which the new one is a variant of?

Answer (score 2):

The following might get you started:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

First version: the same equation number, but without the asterisk DOES NOT exist

\begin{equation}
a + b = c \label{eq:abc1}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
y = x + z  \refstepcounter{equation}\tag{\theequation*} \label{eq:yxz1}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
d + e = f \label{eq:def1}
\end{equation}

\ref{eq:abc1}

\ref{eq:yxz1}

\ref{eq:def1}


Second version: the same equation number, but without the asterisk DOES exist

\begin{equation}
a + b = c \label{eq:abc2}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
y = x + z  \tag{\theequation*} \label{eq:yxz2}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
d + e = f \label{eq:def2}
\end{equation}

\ref{eq:abc2}

\ref{eq:yxz2}

\ref{eq:def2}

\end{document}
```

Comment: That was great!! Thank you so much @leandriis